# dictionary comprehension using list values

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I want to use dictionary/list comprehension to create a dictionary multiple lists.

Here are my 3 lists:

```
city_list = ['new york','boston']
times = ['2021-01-01 19:00:00','2021-01-01 20:00:00']
weather_parameters = ['forecastTimeUtc', 'airtemperature', 'condition']
```

I want to create a dictionary that looks like that:

```
{'new york':[{'forecastTimeUtc': '2021-01-01 20:00:00', 'airTemperature': 0, 'conditionCode': 0}, {'forecastTimeUtc': '2021-01-01 21:00:00', 'airTemperature': 0, 'conditionCode': 0}], 

'boston': [{'forecastTimeUtc': '2021-01-01 20:00:00', 'airTemperature': 0, 'conditionCode': 0}, {'forecastTimeUtc': '2021-01-01 21:00:00', 'airTemperature': 0, 'conditionCode': 0}]}
```

The challenge is to multiply the list that comes after the city based on the how many values are inside of 'forecastTimeUtc'.

The other values for keys 'airTemperature' and 'conditionCode' should stay 0 by default.

Comment: Post your code pls! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In general, we use list comprehensions when they can be concise and make your code elegant. I am afraid that wanting a single dictionary comprehension will confuse the readers of your code and I would suggest building multiple nested for loops.

Nonetheless, here is a dictionary compression that meets your needs:

```py
{city:[{weather_parameter: (time if weather_parameter == 'forecastTimeUtc' else 0) for weather_parameter in weather_parameters} for time in times] for city in city_list}
```

**Step-by-step process**

Without any list comprehension, the code is pretty heavy

```py
weather_per_city = {}
for city in city_list:
    params_list = []
    for time in times:
        param_dict = {}
        for weather_parameter in weather_parameters:
            if weather_parameter == 'forecastTimeUtc':
                param_dict[weather_parameter] = time
            else:    
                param_dict[weather_parameter] = 0
        params_list.append(param_dict)
    weather_per_city[city] = params_list
```

Still no list comprehension, but with a [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) to start simplifying

```py
weather_per_city = {}
for city in city_list:
    params_list = []
    for time in times:
        param_dict = {}
        for weather_parameter in weather_parameters:
            param_dict[weather_parameter] = time if weather_parameter == 'forecastTimeUtc' else 0
        params_list.append(param_dict)
    weather_per_city[city] = params_list
```

First dictionary comprehension:

```py
weather_per_city = {}
for city in city_list:
    params_list = []
    for time in times:
        param_dict = {weather_parameter:(time if weather_parameter == 'forecastTimeUtc' else 0) for weather_parameter in weather_parameters}
        params_list.append(param_dict)
    weather_per_city[city] = params_list
```

And with a second comprehension (dictionary + list):

```py
weather_per_city = {}
for city in city_list:
    params_list = [{weather_parameter:(time if weather_parameter == 'forecastTimeUtc' else 0) for weather_parameter in weather_parameters} for time in times]
    weather_per_city[city] = params_list
```

Comment: Since i'm struggling. How would the same logic look in a nested for loop?

Comment: @KaroGr I've updated my post to display the same logic with 0, 1 and 2 list comprehensions.

Comment: Thank you! My problem was creating all empty dictionaries and list before the for loops. This makes total sense now.

Comment: @KaroGr If this answers your question, please mark my response as 'Answer'